# Why does the box come out like this (padding/border/margin)?

Tags: html, css, border, margin, padding

So this is my first day learning HTML&CSS and I'm currently having a problem. Why does this block come out like this (on left is what I get & on right is what I'm trying to achieve):

[image]

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Temporary</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main2.css">
</head>
<body id="top">

<code id="boxone">Welcome! <br>Dashed border</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
code {
background: #5CC7FF;
font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
padding: 2px;
margin-top: 1px;
margin-left: 1px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
margin-right: 4px;
text-align: center;
}

#boxone {
border: 8px dashed #5CA8FF;
}
```

The problem is that I want it to come out as a blue dashed box, but instead it comes out as two messed-up boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `<code>` elements have a [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) of `inline` (which is going to generate an element box for every one of the parts separated by `<br>`).

Switching to `display: block` (`code { display: block }` in your CSS) or `display: inline-block` will mean creating just one element box for your `<code>`.

```css
code {
  display: block;
  background: #5CC7FF;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 1px 4px 4px 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

#boxone {
  border: 8px dashed #5CA8FF;
}

code:nth-child(2) { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<code id="boxone">Welcome! <br>Dashed border</code>
<code id="boxone">Welcome! <br>Dashed border</code>
```

Comment: [fancy a chat?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/css-shapes-and-designs)

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:block;` to your code css. Also fix this line:

```
<code id="boxone">Welcome! <br>Dashed border</div>      <= </code>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rdgdz07o/
Use it for testing stuff out.